# Calling .NET DLL function with type parameter from PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell, dll, type-parameter

I'm trying to make a PowerShell script using the DocumentFormat.OpenXml library. Everything is working fairly well, except that I'm struggling with syntax for passing type parameters. Specifically, I'm working with the [`DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement.Descendants`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.openxmlelement.descendants?view=openxml-2.8.1) method. I can easily call it like this:

```
using assembly /root/.nuget/packages/documentformat.openxml/2.17.1/lib/net40/DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll;
using namespace DocumentFormat.OpenXml;

$Output = Resolve-Path "$(Get-Location)\out.docx"
$myDoc = [WordprocessingDocument]::Open($Output, $true)
$mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants()
```

This returns all of the descendants. However, I'd really like to call `$mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<FormFieldData>()` to get only descendants of that type. Unfortunately, PowerShell doesn't like the `<>` syntax. It gives me this message:

```
At line:1 char:36
+ $mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<FormFieldData>()
+                                    ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
```

I'm sure this is simply a matter of not knowing the correct PowerShell syntax, but my Google skills are failing me and I can't seem to find the correct syntax.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calling_generic_methods?view=powershell-7.3 Try `$mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants[FormFieldData]()`

Comment: @Charlieface nice! Unfortunately I'm on version 5 for the moment so that syntax doesn't work. Perhaps I can fix the version, since the link you sent seems to indicate that prior to version 7 things were a lot harder.

Comment: @Charlieface that got me there! Thank you! If you make this an answer, then I will mark it as the solution.

Once I copied the script from that answer, I was able to do:

`.\Invoke-GenericMethod.ps1 -instance $mainPart.Document.Body -methodName Descendants -typeParameters DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.FormFieldData -methodParameters $null`

Comment: You should have a button above to accept the link as a duplicate